# CiviMobile not connecting in Joomla

Tags: joomla, mobile

Joomla 3.9.3
CiviCRM 5.10.3
CiviMobile 1.3.1
App on iPhone
http://crm.mydomain.xx
admin account

App always comes up with "unknow error" - demo works.

THX4HELP
Frank

Comment: Do you have still a problem? Please feel free to write me andriy.stabryn@agiliway.com if you still have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are installing this extension

https://civicrm.org/extensions/civimobileapi/